# Разбор слова "ощущение" по составу

Tags: морфемный-разбор

Помогите разобрать по составу слово "ощущение".
У меня получился такой разбор: ощущенийэ, корень ощущ, суффиксы ен, ий , окончание э

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Помогите разобрать по составу слово "ощущение".

**Ощут**ить -> ощу*щ*-**ени[й** + (э)]

-- корень **ощущ-** + суффикс **-ениj-** + окончание **-е**.

===

См. у Литневской (http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part2.htm#9 ):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наверное, ощутить - ощущать - ощущение?

Comment: А зачем так? "Щ" ведь не принадлежность глагола _"ощущать";_ эта буква имеется и в формах глагола _"ощутить": ощущу, ощущённый_ (прич.). Хотя я тоже хотел было образовать _"ощущение"_ от _"ощущать"_, но заглянул в Тихонова, а там:
_ощутить -> ощущать; ощутить -> ощущение…_

Comment: Просто интересно: чувство - это то, что чувствуешь, ощущение - это то, что ощутил или то, что ощущаешь?

Comment: У Ефремовой -- "процесс действия по гл. _ощущать_ " (http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/207806  ). === 

У Тихонова -- "действие по глаг. _ощутить_" (Словарь-справочник по русскому языку. М., 1997).